# Move multiple files in different directories into a new folder

Tags: windows, cmd.exe

I am facing a problem moving multiple files from different folders to one single folder.

All my files are ending with `.las` and are located in a path like this : `e:\LiDAR\%%%%\LIDAR*\`, where `%%%%` is a serie of 4 numbers like 0950, and where `LiDAR*` is the beggining of all the different folder names containing the `.las` files.

Here's an exemple of path of one of the `.las` file :

```
E:\LiDAR\0950\LIDARHD_1-0_LAZ_PK-0950_6535-2021\Semis_2021_0950_6535_LA93_IGN69.las
```

I want to move all those files to a folder I created, here is its path :

```
E:\LiDAR\Las_files
```

Here's the command line I tried but it's not working :

```
E:\>move e:\LiDAR\%%%%\LIDAR*\*.las e:\LiDAR\Las_files\
```

I would be happy if someone can help me : )

Comment: Are you literally using the `%%%%` in your command, or are you trying this with a specific number first?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this in Powershell:

```
Get-ChildItem -Path "E:\LiDAR" -Filter *.las -Recurse | Move-Item -Destination "E:\LiDAR\Las_files" -Whatif
```

This should move every .las file from all sub-folders into the las_files folder.

Answer (score 0):

Your attempt would have worked in Bash, but Cmd.exe has no "generic" wildcard processing (it's done on a case-by-case basis, with `move` and `del` doing it differently), so instead you'll need to use `for` and loop through each directory:

```
for /d %x in (e:\lidar\####\lidar*) do move %x\*.las e:\lidar\las_files\
```

(Note that if you put this in a .bat/.cmd script, the `%x` must be written as `%%x`.)

If you need to loop through numbered directories, you'll need a second (outer) `for` loop for that.